# PostConstruct in CDI SessionScoped managed beans

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, cdi, managed-bean, weld

Short story: I have a CDI `@SessionScoped` bean (annotation from `javax.enterprise.context` and not from `javax.faces`) called `UserContextBean`. I'd like to actually do something when an HTTP session is created.

So naturally I assumed that `@PostConstruct` would do the trick: get called only once when an instance of this bean is constructed.
However, as per the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmgkd.html), they say that the PostConstruct method is called :

> When the managed bean is injected into a component, CDI calls the
>   method after all injection has occurred and after all initializers
>   have been called.

I had assumed that the post construct method would be called once, per session. However, practice is consistent with the documentation. This bean is injected into a `@RequestScoped` bean (also CDI) which serves as a backing bean for a JSF page and the PostConstruct method is called **for every request**.

I realize (now) that this is the behavior. But would there be any other way of doing a one time per session initialization?

Some code, although not very relevant:

```
@Named(UserContextBean.BEAN_NAME)
@SessionScoped
public class UserContextBean implements Serializable {

...

    @PostConstruct
    private void createSession() {
        System.out.println("UserContext created.");
    }
}
```

The request scoped bean where I inject this:

```
public abstract class WebPageDataProvider extends AbstractViewDataProvider {

    @Inject
    private UserContextBean userContext;
```

I was also thinking to use an `HttpSessionListener` and initialize the session bean, but it already sounds messy.

**EDIT**

Just noticed now that the HTTP session is not even created. If I create the session "manually", by calling `getSession(true)` (I do this inside a phase listener, for testing purposes, but only because it was already there) then everything works as expected.

Comment: How is your UI built?

Comment: @JohnAment: Well, it's JSF 2 (Mojarra). The specific page I'm testing with is very simple. It's derived from a template and just brings together a couple of facelets. The EL expression that uses the request scoped bean is in the actual page, not in the facelets and just accesses a text property in the bean (which uses the user context bean to get a user role).

Comment: Ok, good.  Sorry, what about CDI implementation and container?  If you're using tomcat, are you using CDI via servlet?

Answer (score 0):

An HttpSessionListener is your best bet. What you could do is inject a SessionScoped component into the listener and set the value there.